# Nodejs neo4j-driver Trying to read and return result set of over 4m records

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

[UPDATE]
I had a few good recommendations on the Neo4j community forum here: https://community.neo4j.com/t/nodejs-neo4j-driver-trying-to-read-and-return-result-set-of-over-4m-records/22705/13

Suggestion 1) Only search on Campaigns with an Industry Sector ID - so add a label to Campaign nodes with an industry sector ID 'HasIndustrySector'.

Suggestion 2) Split the query into two parts: 1st part, grab all campaigns with industry sector. 2nd Part, Aggregate the relationships to be optionally searched together as such:

```
MATCH (c:Campaign)
WHERE c.industrySectorId IS NOT NULL
RETURN id(c) as campaignId

MATCH (c)-[r:SENT_EMAIL|OPENED|CLICKED]-(p)
WHERE id(c) = $campaignId
WITH c, type(r) as type, count(distinct p) as count LIMIT 1000
WITH c, {type: type, count: count} as data
WITH c, collect(data) as totals
RETURN c.campaignId AS campaignId, c.industrySectorId AS industrySectorId, c.senddate AS sendDate, c.subjectLine AS subject, c.preHeader AS preHeader, totals
```

This has actually resulted in the query completing. The result of profile on this query is:

134178426 total db hits in 5 ms (it says 5ms, but it definitely took around 50+ seconds to actually complete and return the result of the profile).

[image]

[ORIGNAL QUESTION]

We have a new server running dedicated enterprise Neo4j.

Recently imported data from MSSQL database producing around 100m nodes and equal number of relationships.

I have connected the neo4j-driver for nodejs fine and run many queries successfully.

However, I am at a point where I need to read/stream around 4 million records from a particular node label.

I have used both session and reactive session to try to do this, but the results just never appear, even if I leave it for hours. However, if I put a LIMIT clause on the query, I get results fine for anything up to 500,000. However, going above this there is just no response at all and also I can't see anything in the logs.

Here is the query:

```
cypher runtime=slotted 
MATCH (c:Campaign)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[:HAS]-(i:IndustrySector)
WITH c,i
OPTIONAL MATCH (c {campaignId: c.campaignId})-[sent:SENT_EMAIL]->(sp:Person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c {campaignId: c.campaignId})<-[opened:OPENED]-(op:Person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c {campaignId: c.campaignId})<-[clicked:CLICKED]-(cp:Person)
WITH c, i, COUNT(DISTINCT(sp)) AS totalSent, COUNT(DISTINCT(op)) AS totalOpened, COUNT(DISTINCT(cp)) AS totalClicked
RETURN c.campaignId AS campaignId, i.industrySectorId AS industrySectorId, c.senddate AS sendDate, c.subjectLine AS subject, c.preHeader AS preHeader, totalSent, totalOpened, totalClicked
```

As you can see I have set the cypher runtime to use slotted. I have tried this without but it seems to send the entire results back in one batch, rather than streaming row by row.

Here are two versions I have tried, first is normal session. The second is using reactive session:

```
// Normal Session
session.run(query)
.subscribe({
onKeys: keys => {
},
onNext: record => {
},
onCompleted: () => {
},
onError: error => {
}});

// Reactive Session
rxSession.run(query)
.records()
.pipe(map(record => record.toObject()))
.subscribe({
...same as above
})
```

One other thing I tried was to use SKIP and LIMIT on the query so processing in batches of 10k records. This works fine until it reaches 520,000 records then just hangs again.

Would be very grateful if anyone is able to point me to where I am going wrong or a better way to achieve what I want. I have looked at the apoc library such as apoc.periodic.iterate however that is only applicable to performing write operations.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: A few questions to help add context: What version of Neo4j? What's the heap size set to be? What does a PROFILE on that query look like? What indexes are in place? How many of each node label and relationship type are there?

Comment: Neo4j v4.1.1 . Heap size is set to default because in the configuration it says it automatically adjusts based on system. Profile on the query doesn't complete unless I add a limit clause. Campaign has index on campaignId, no other indexes are used. Approx. 100m Person nodes, 100m relationships being traversed, and 4m campaigns.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations:

1. You should not use `DISTINCT` in `COUNT(DISTINCT x)` when unnecessary, as that forces the query to accumulate in memory a set of **all** the distinct values found thus far and to check each new value against that list -- so that it can give you an accurate count. In your query, the `sp`, `op`, and `cp` values should have been naturally distinct anyway (assuming you never have multiple relationships of the same type between the same pair of nodes). So, if you had just used `COUNT(x)` instead, the query could have simply incremented a counter to get each count. *However, the query below does not need to use `COUNT` at all.*
2. When possible, you should avoid traversing relationships or getting nodes if you don't have to. In your case, you could have gotten the counts *very quickly* using a Cypher pattern like `SIZE((x)-[:FOO]->())` that [leverages the internal GetDegree() operation](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-counting-number-of-relationships-on-a-node/).
3. The `industrySectorId` value is completely independent of the counts. So, you should not be expending an effort to get all the counts *for each* `industrySectorId`, since the counts would never change between `industrySectorId`s. The query below just collects all the `industrySectorId` values in a list, and does each count just once.
4. `(c {campaignId: c.campaignId})` is unnecessarily torturous. It should just have been `(c)`.

This query should be *much* faster:

```
MATCH (c:Campaign)
RETURN
  c.campaignId AS campaignId,
  c.senddate AS sendDate, c.subjectLine AS subject, c.preHeader AS preHeader,
  [(c)<-[:HAS]-(i:IndustrySector) | i.industrySectorId] AS industrySectorIds,
  SIZE((c)-[:SENT_EMAIL]->()) AS totalSent,
  SIZE((c)<-[:OPENED]-()) AS totalOpened,
  SIZE((c)<-[:CLICKED]-()) AS totalClicked
```

It uses quick GetDegree() checks to get the counts without actually traversing any relationships or getting any nodes at the other end. It also just puts all the `industrySectorId` values in a single `industrySectorIds`. This way, each result row contains all the desired data for each `Campaign`.

[UPDATE]

Since you have indicated that there can indeed be multiple relationships of the same type between a `Campaign` and the same `Person`, #1 and #2 above do not apply to you.

The following query should still be faster than your query, since it uses #3 (to avoid repeating the same set of expensive queries per `IndustrySector`) and #4, and does the `MATCH/COUNT` steps one-at-a-time to avoid cartesian products:

```
MATCH (c:Campaign)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:SENT_EMAIL]->(sp:Person)
WITH c, COUNT(DISTINCT sp) AS totalSent
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[:OPENED]-(op:Person)
WITH c, totalSent, COUNT(DISTINCT op) AS totalOpened
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[clicked:CLICKED]-(cp:Person)
WITH c, totalSent, totalOpened, COUNT(DISTINCT cp) AS totalClicked
RETURN
  c.campaignId AS campaignId,
  c.senddate AS sendDate, c.subjectLine AS subject, c.preHeader AS preHeader,
  [(c)<-[:HAS]-(i:IndustrySector) | i.industrySectorId] AS industrySectorIds,
  totalSent,
  totalOpened,
  totalClicked
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth reply. However, the problem is exactly what you noted; There are multiple relationships of the same type between the same pair of nodes. There is a reason for this, and that is because Person(s) can open/click/receive emails on different devices, and we want to track this.
So unfortunately this is why I added in the distinct clauses.

Comment: OK, see my UPDATE.

Comment: Thanks. This is certainly an improvement, however the query is still taking an exceptionally long time (in fact it just doesn't complete). I think it may be because there are fringe cases were there are tens of these similar relationships between the nodes. When I limit it, it works fine. It's like when it gets to a certain point it has to traverse so many of these. I asked a similar question in Neo4j community and had a few other suggestions - I will add as an update to my question.